# How to activate keyboard shortcut for synchronize-panes?

Tags: tmux

Via the pragmatic programmer, one of their [`.tmux.conf`](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/bhtmux/code/workflows/tmux.conf) files has this for "synchronize-panes":

```
# shortcut for synchronize-panes toggle
# START:sync
bind C-s set-window-option synchronize-panes
# END:sync
```

I do not know how to run this. I find myself running `setw synchronize-panes` a lot both to turn this on and off. How can I send a keyboard shortcut to run this in tmux? A simple `C-s` does not work while using the `.tmux.conf` above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your bind command means you have to press the prefix key (<kbd>Control-b</kbd> by default) then <kbd>Control-s</kbd> to run the command. If you want to just press <kbd>Control-s</kbd> then add the option `-n` to the bind:

```
bind -n C-s set-window-option synchronize-panes
```

Comment: Excellent, this also works for turn off if press second time.